# Выбор между OS X и Linux для программиста c++

Tags: linux, macos

Перебираюсь с винды на UNIX, но пока не решился на какой именно. В целом мне нравятся (слабо сказано) ноутбуки apple, но сначала хочу узнать какие преимущества Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) может дать программисту, которые будут недоступны на Mac OS X?

Работаю преимущественно на С++ в сфере финансов. В качестве хобби занимаюсь олимпиадным программированием, опять же на плюсах.

Буду рад любым советам от людей использовавших обе ОС.

Comment: А в чем лучше всего писать код срр на OS X?

Comment: Переходил с линукса на мак, настроил такое же окружение и в результате принципиальной разницы для программирования не увидел

Comment: @magic: под OS X есть Eclipse и Intellij IDEA, обе вроде как работают с c++. Ну, всякие там Sublime и Vim тоже никто не отменял )))

Comment: Проголосовал за переоткрытие. На мой взгляд, выбор достаточно конкретизирован: автору нужно продолжить разработку на [tag:c++] в удобной среде и получить все преимущества UNIX.

Answer (score 6):

Использую и **Mac OS X**, и **Linux Debian**.

И там, и там можно использовать `btsync`, `dropbox`, `vim`, `emacs`, `firefox`, `chrome`, `skype`, `python`, `perl`, `clang`, `gcc`, `ruby`, `fish`, `zsh` и прочее.

**Darwin** (OS X, iOS)

- Маки не бьются. Только мнутся. Или только экран.
- Много красивых приложений с хорошим граф. интерфейсом.
- Очень доступная техподдержка.
- UNIX-подобная система.
- Не нужно заморачиваться по поводу конфигов так, как на **Linux**, и в особенности, как на **FreeBSD**.
- Отсутствует поддержка некоторых чуть ли не стандартных вещей **Linux**. Например, нет единого пакетного менеджера (помимо App Store) или папки `/etc/init.d`. Может, в этом отношении **Linux** в терминале поудобнее будет.
- Разрабатывается компанией **Apple**, которая является настолько крупной, что порой идет настречу не программистам, а домохозяйкам. В этом есть свои минусы.

**Linux** (Debian, LinuxMint, Ubuntu, Fedora, RedHat, CentOs, ArchLinux, openSuSe, Android, ...)

- Много дистрибутивов. Может вызвать поначалу трудности.
- Больше консольных утилит.
- Может запускаться в удобном консольном режиме, в отличие от **Safe Mode** в **OS X**. Так съедается меньше оперативки.
- Поскольку дистрибутивов очень большое множество, а их конфигураций еще больше, то, на мой взгляд, **Linux** чуть-чуть более защищен. Если у вас не сервер, должно быть без разницы.
- С **[открытым исходным кодом](https://github.com/torvalds/linux)**.
- Ядро **Linux** весит полтора гигобайта (насколько я помню). В **OS X** 8 изначально, но в меньше 50 гигов при трех основных (`brew` `port` `fink`) пакетных менеджерах трудно уместиться.

Оценка, естественно, субъективна, так как на данный момент из **Linux** использую только **Debian** в качестве сервера.

Я попытался выделить самое основное в данном списке, но скорее всего я что-то упустил.

Comment: а finder разве не единый пакетный менеджер? может это нубский вопрос, но я не силен в UNIX)

Comment: @magic finder - это обычный проводник. Позволяет перемещаться по папкам и управлять папками и файлами. Пакетный менеджер, если сильно упростить, это программа управляющая установкой и удалением других программ и дополнений к ним. Для установки компилятора C++ в Debian со всеми плюшками нужно установить 19 пакетов (выполняется 1 командой): `dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.7 gcc gcc-4.7 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libdpkg-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl libitm1 libstdc++6-4.7-dev libtimedate-perl linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev`

Comment: @magic: в качестве пакетного менеджера установите Homebrew: http://brew.sh/

Comment: @atom-22 Есть гораздо более простая команда: `apt-get install g++`. Сам ей всегда устанавливал

Comment: Ещё можно на mac установить винду, чтобы остаться в привычной среде.

Answer (score 5):

Занимался программированием и там и там, кроме вкусовых предпочтений, существенной разницы нет. Комфортное программирование вполне возможно и в Ubuntu и на Mac OS X.

Разве что сообщество Ubuntu мне показалось более активным и более отзывчивым.

По обеим ОС есть замечательные сайты на StackExchange: так что при желании сможете разобраться.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/

https://askubuntu.com/

p.s. Вопрос холиварный, лучше его максимально конкретизировать.

Comment: спасибо за Ваш ответ!
Много просто говорят про то, что терминал OS X не дает полной свободы в отличии от linux, но редко поясняет в чем именно это заключается - не замечали ли Вы чего такого?

Насчет холливарности согласен, но меня интересуют в основном подводные камни - в духе "хотел сделать на такой-то оси вот это, а она не позволяет".
Еще по безопасности хотелось узнать нюансы.

Comment: `> Много просто говорят про то, что терминал OS X не дает полной свободы в отличии от linux`

Я думаю, лучше всего спрашивать в таких случаях у тех, кто так говорит, что они имеют ввиду?

Comment: Речь шла о старых холливарах на хабре, StackExchange и не хотелось заниматься некромантией, поэтому решил отдельно задать вопрос - к тому же вдруг что изменилось в 15 году?